# Is a sig. fixed effect intercept in a variance components model (without specified IV) similar to a sig. one-sample t-test?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test

I ran a variance components model with Y ~ + 1 + (1|participant) + (1|item), and the p-value for the fixed effect intercept (even though there is no fixed effect specified) in the summary is < .0001 – can I say that Y is sig. different from 0 (i.e. like in a one sample t-test) or does it mean something else? If I can't say that, but still want to know whether Y is sig. different from 0, are there other options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the essence is the same. The only difference here is that you have fitted a variance components model and are taking account of repeated measures within participants and items (otherwise the data would likely not be independent). If you fail to account for such non-independence then the p-values you obtain may be wrong.

You can say that if the overall expectation of Y is really zero, then the probability of observing the data that you did, or indeed data more extreme, is less than 0.0001

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if you haven't already please consider upvoting it. If not, please let us know why ?